# External storage and HTC One V

Tags: java, android, storage

I tested my app on a HTC One V a few weeks ago. When my app checked the availability of the external storage at its first run, it got that there is none. (I used `getExternalStorageState()` and based on the result,  `getExternalFilesDir(null)`).

I read the relevant stackoverflow thread (and Android doc), so I came to the conclusion that any device supporting Google Play must offer some sort of external storage (SD card or else). The Android official homepages also imply that `getExternalFilesDir` must always return a valid place (unless unmounted, or mounted to PC etc.).

The owner of the HTC One V who allowed me to perform the test told me that he did not get any SD card to his phone. (I know external storage can be something else as well, but as you can see above, the standard `getExternalStorageState` call returned that there is none, i.e. it did not return the internal storage of HTC One V.)

If I turned off the external storage usage of my app (and instead relied on phone memory instead), everything worked fine on One V. The problem is, it is a game, which will be greater than 50MB, so I am forced to use Google's APK Expansion Files possibility -- and that requires external storage.

Do vendors/mobile operators have the right to sell the phone without an external storage (in this case, without an SD card)? I know this is not really a dev question, but as you can see, something must be wrong here. As far as I can see, One V has a big internal storage, so I wonder why `getExternalStorageState` didn't report it as available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have designed an [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.torcellite.whatsappduplicatemediaremover&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50b3JjZWxsaXRlLndoYXRzYXBwZHVwbGljYXRlbWVkaWFyZW1vdmVyIl0.) which although doesn't require External Storage works with files in the "external storage". Whatsapp too works on a `HTC One V`, so obviously there's a problem with your code.

The thing is, in my application although the `minSdkVersion="8"` I didn't use `getExternalFilesDir(null)`. Instead I used [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29), this wasn't because of choice. I wasn't aware of the `getExternalFilesDir()` function while developing the application. However, the app works as it should on a friend's `HTC One V`. So I would suggest that you use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Sample code:

```
String mountStatus = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if (mountStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("mounted")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: I haven't tested the code, but that's the gist of it to obtain the external storage directory.

Comment: I used the official google code, I doubt my code had issues. It must have been something with that particular One V, I think.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean the devices with internal storage have an issue with `getExternalFilesDir()` not your particular code. No offense :)

Comment: It's OK, thanks :) I'm going to test it again as soon as I get access to that device again.

Comment: I verified it, and unfortunately, it does not work on this HTC One V. The real question is, are manufacturers allowed to assign an optional drive to the "external storage" API? Because this HTC One V was purchased without the external SD card, yet the API points to the SD card (instead of the internal storage)...